# How to check if an image was found on a web site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image, web

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.0.9 and I would like to *check if an image* (in my case a `favicon.ico` icon image) *is successfully retrieved from a web site and if not I would like to display a custom image*.

In order to retrieve the `favicon.ico` image related to a web site, in my view file I have:

```
image_tag "#{web_site.link}/favicon.ico", :size => "16x16"
```

where `web_site.link` values are something like the followings:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/
http://facebook.com/
...
```

**How to check if an image was found on a web site** (maybe using an `if ... else ... end` statement or performing some HTTP request before to handle favicon images) **and how to handle the above scenario?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to implement the idea you had in the original question.

The issue with this approach will be that your response times will include however long it takes for the other domain to respond to your request for the image.  If that site is having 
 issues, then your page wont load until the request times out.

```
<%
img_url = 'http://adomain.com/image.jpg'
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(img_url))
img_url = '[my alternate url]' unless res.code.to_i >= 200 && res.code.to_i < 400 #good codes will be betweem 200 - 399
%>

<%=image_tag img_url%>
```

The jQuery approach is a bit more involved.  I'd suggest something along the following:

- create an `<img>` tag with a transparent spacer image
- in the page's javascript run a `$.ajax` call for the remote image

  - in the success callback replace the `<img>`'s src with the remote images's url
  - in the failure callback replace the `<img>`'s src with the fallback image's url

Unfortunately, I don't have time to generate the exact code for this right now.

Comment: "Unfortunately, I don't have time to generate the exact code for this right now." :'-( ... I will try my self...

Comment: Why you use `to_f` here? Is it possible the status code is a float rather than int?

Comment: @new2cpp no idea why I used `to_f`, editing response

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with Rails unless you fetch the image server-side before rendering the page. What you could do is fetch it in the client with a JavaScript and if there's trouble retrieving it, then switch to an alternative.

Comment: How can I fetch the image server-side before rendering the page with JavaScript (I am using jQuery 1.6)?

Comment: You've got options in both regards, but the [curb](http://curb.rubyforge.org/) gem might be the best option. Also it's either download server-side *or* client-side with JavaScript, not both. It's just that someone has to verify the link works, you just need to pick who. If you're doing this server-side, you'd probably want to run it as a background process that populates a mapping table.

Comment: Why do you advice me to use the 'curb' gem and not the Ruby standard library?

Comment: BTW: I have also heard of the Typhoeus gem. What about that?

Comment: `curb` is built on libcurl, and it offers more features than the built in `Net::HTTP` library. I also think it's easier to use, but there are alternatives all of which do similar things.